# SQL join on columns of same table with MAX on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have this table (top row is column names):

```
security    quote_type      price     round   
sec_1       bid             3.4       1
sec_1       ask             3.6       1
sec_1       bid             3.5       2
sec_1       ask             3.7       2
sec_2       bid             5.2       1
sec_2       ask             5.4       1
sec_3       bid             2.3       1 
sec_4       ask             7.8       1
sec_4       ask             7.9       2
```

Need to achieve these results:

```
security    bid     ask      round
sec_1       3.5     3.7      2 
sec_2       5.2     5.4      1
sec_3       2.3     null     1
sec_4       null    7.9      2
```

Have this much working, which does not yet take into account the "round" column:

```
select security,
   max(case when quote_type = 'bid' then price end) as bid,
   max(case when quote_type = 'ask' then price end) as ask
from t
group by security;
```

There will always be at most one bid and one ask price per security, per round.

Using SQL Server.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you add in your own words what are you trying to do?

Comment: What happens when the largest value of bid is round 1 and the largest ask is in round 2? Which one do you want returned?

Comment: Simply `MAX(round)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the maximum round for each security.  Here is one method:

```
select security,
       max(case when quote_type = 'bid' then price end) as bid,
       max(case when quote_type = 'ask' then price end) as ask
from (select t.*, max(round) over (partition by security) as max_round
      from t
     ) t
where round = max_round
group by security;
```

Comment: Why not just MAX(round) as a fourth column? Don't really need a subquery here do we?

Comment: The problem with MAX(round) is that it might not line up with the MAX bid or ask

Comment: @SeanLange . . . Because the max of the bid/ask might not come from the highest round.

Comment: Wasn't sure if they wanted the max round for the security or the highest round where either a 'bid' or 'ask' was made.

Answer (score 0):

**Create table and insert data:**

```
CREATE TABLE [security] (security VARCHAR(10),quote_type VARCHAR(10),price NUMERIC(3,1),round INT)

INSERT INTO [security]
SELECT 'sec_1','bid','3.4','1'
UNION SELECT 'sec_1','ask','3.6','1'
UNION SELECT 'sec_1','bid','3.5','2'
UNION SELECT 'sec_1','ask','3.7','2'
UNION SELECT 'sec_2','bid','5.2','1'
UNION SELECT 'sec_2','ask','5.4','1'
UNION SELECT 'sec_3','bid','2.3','1'
UNION SELECT 'sec_4','ask','7.8','1'
UNION SELECT 'sec_4','ask','7.9','2'

select * From [security]
```

**Requested resulset:**

```
  ;with cte_max_round as (
        SELECT security,MAX(Round) R FROM [security]
        group by security
        )

    SELECT B.security,BID.price,ASK.price,r Round 
    FROM cte_max_round B 
    LEFT JOIN [security] ASK 
        ON B.security = ASK.security AND B.R = ASK.[round] AND ASK.quote_type = 'ask' 
    LEFT JOIN [security] BID 
        ON B.security = BID.security AND B.R = BID.[round] AND BID.quote_type = 'bid'
```